# image unlink from folder but can't delete from database column

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I'm learning php and mysql. Right now I need some help with delete image using $_GET method. I can unlink image from folder but not from database column. Here is my database structure for `userinfo` table columns are-

> user_id| username| email| password| department| position| first_name|
>   last_name| status| user_pic| join_date| modified

Here is my php code:

```
 <?php
  include 'sql.php';
  if(isset($_GET['delete_id']))
   {
    // select image from db to delete
    $select_img = mysql_query("SELECT user_pic FROM userinfo WHERE user_pic
    =" .$_GET['delete_id']);

    $db_field= mysql_fetch_array($select_img);

    unlink("assets/img/user_images/".$db_field['user_pic']);
   //delete from db
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM userinfo WHERE user_id=".$_GET['delete_id']);

    if($select_img===false){
    die(mysql_error());
    }

    else
    {?>
    <script>
        window.alert('Delete images Success!!!');
       </script>
     <?php
      header("refresh:2;user_profile_settings.php");
    }
  }

?>
// here is the HTML part Which display using while loop
<a  class="btn close" href="?delete_id=<?php echo $userpic; ?>" title="click    
 for delete" onclick="return confirm('sure to delete ?')"  >&times;</a>
 <img src="assets/img/user_images/<?php echo $userpic; ?>" />
```

I know this is pretty simple code.. I want to learn thats why I'm posting this. I already tired lots of Technic but every time I failed. Please Help me out with this. 
Advance Thanks

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), so don't worry - your "can't delete from database" problem will be resolved soon, as soon as someone deletes your entire database for you. Plus, you're LYING about the delete success. You don't check the status of the "delete" query, ONLY the original "select" query, so you're simply ASSUMING nothing could ever go wrong.

Comment: You wanna delete image using UserID? if it is you should edit this first: user_pic =" .$_GET['delete_id']

Comment: @MarcB sir i'm learning the basic . I know about that attack. And why should I lied for learning. unlink() function work its true. 
Anyways thanks for your advice

Comment: Want to delete image or user info

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** `mysql_*` functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: @devpro want to unlink image from folder which is done, But I also want to delete from database.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Thanks for the suggestion, will start PDO soon.

Comment: Than delete image not profile

Comment: @devpro thats what i'm trying .. only unlink work .. or some times theke entire row of the user deteted. :(

Comment: U just need yo use as `DELETE FROM userinfo WHERE user_pic=".$_GET['delete_id']`

Comment: If the user info and image both in same table in single row than u can use update and set empty the image column

Comment: @devpro yes last night got this solution from MR. Babydead. And userinfo(table) contain the user_id and user_pic column in same row. I have attached my database userinfo(table) columns with my question. 
It was my mistake I didn't mention columns.

Comment: I suggest u yo use separate table for images otherwise u have empty columns extra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DELETE FROM` deletes the entire row.
I'm pretty sure it refuses because of `foreign keys` or something.

If you only want to empty the column, you should use `UPDATE`

```
$query = "UPDATE userinfo SET user_pic='' WHERE user_id='$_GET['delete_id']'";
mysql_query($query);
```

You should also listen to what the others are saying and think about switching to MYSQLI, but more importantly, preventing SQL injection!

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution. And soon I will switching to MYSQLi.

Comment: Better solution